# MySQL: Direct Update or Select before a conditional Update?

Tags: database, performance, updates

Just curious to know- if we need to do a conditional Update in a **large** table, then which is the best approach-

Directly doing an Update or check for existing entry before Update.

```
function doDirectUpdate()
{
   // UPDATE table WHERE condn
}
```

OR

```
function doCheckAndUpdate()
{
   // SELECT COUNT(id) AS exist FROM table WHERE condn
   if(id exists)
   {
      // UPDATE table WHERE condn
   }
   else
   {
      echo 'No matching entry';
   }
}
```

Comment: Did the answer provided help you to figure out which approach to take?

Comment: But want to know the answer regarding to performance. If we consider a table with millions of data, The second approach will take double time for existing id s.

Comment: You should not be if any rows exist, but rather just updating the matching rows.  The only time that you should perform the select is if you have other logic that states to not update if there are more than X matching rows.  As UPDATE returns the number of rows updated, and therefor matched, you should take that return value to determine if you need to echo 'No matching entry'.

Comment: gr8. +1. plz update ur Answer & will accept that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should not perform both a `SELECT`, then a conditional `UPDATE`, simply to display the number of matching rows -- or lack of matching rows.  The only time that you should perform the `SELECT` is if you have other logic that states to not update if there are more than X matching rows.

`UPDATE` returns the number of rows that were updated, and therefor matched.  You should take the return value, from `UPDATE`, then alert if there are no matching entries.

```
function doUpdateAndAlertIfNotMatched()
{
   numberOfRowsUpdated = UPDATE table WHERE condn;
   if(numberOfRowsUpdated == 0)
   {
      echo 'No matching entry';
   }
}
```

reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html#id844302